# Columns not Inline for two TCCV Sections using Supertabular

Tags: macros, supertabular

**I have two separate sections which both use my new `\tableentry` I'm confused as to why the alignment is different for the two sections. Any pointers or ideas would be greatly appreciated!**

[image: Im confused why the two table entries are not inline for the two different sections]

**Here is my Main file code**

```
    \begin{supertabular}{rl} % Start a table with two columns, the table will ensure everything is aligned

    %------------------------------------------------

    \tableentry{Beginner}{\LaTeX, MiniTab, ExtendSIM, Vulcan}{spaceafter}

    %------------------------------------------------

    \tableentry{Intermediate}{Excel, Python}{}
    \tableentry{}{Microsoft Windows}{}
    \tableentry{}{Computer Hardware \& Support}{spaceafter}

    %------------------------------------------------

    \tableentry{Expert}{Perl, Unix}{spaceafter}

    %------------------------------------------------

\end{supertabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMMUNICATION SKILLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Language Abilities}
% Example \tableentry{} command to add another line:

%\tableentry{Heading}{Content}{spaceafter}


\begin{supertabular}{rl} % Start a table with two columns, the table will ensure everything is aligned

    %------------------------------------------------

    \tableentry{French}{Working Proficiency}{spaceafter}
%   \tableentry{}{}{spaceafter}

    %------------------------------------------------

    \tableentry{Spanish}{Working Proficiency}{spaceafter}
%   \tableentry{}{}{spaceafter}

    %------------------------------------------------

    \tableentry{Russian}{Fluent}{spaceafter}
%   \tableentry{}{}{spaceafter}

    %------------------------------------------------

    \tableentry{English}{Fluent}{spaceafter}
%   \tableentry{}{}{spaceafter}

    %------------------------------------------------
```

**Here is my Document structure code for the table entry command**

```
\newcommand{\tableentry}[3]{
    \textsc{#1} & #2\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#3}{}{\\}{\\[6pt]} %
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please be more specific about what you're looking to do; I can deduce it from this, but I shouldn't have to.  Posting screenshots and code is vital; but a clear explanation of your problem and what you've already tried to do to solve it is also vital.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii I'm excited to be here and hanks for the heads up! I have edited my post.

Comment: As far as I can see, you have two different tables, and the content of the first column have different length in the first and second tabular.

Comment: Your code does not compile, so it is impossible to give further advice.